# javascript, html document.write

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I'm trying to write a javascript using document.write but for some reasons it doesn't work . I also need to make a kind of trick to 'obfuscate' the url and "src" attribute by automated bots .Any idea why ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<scr\" + \"ipt type=\"text\/jav\" + \"ascript\"  s\" + \"rc=\"http:\/\/www.a\" + \"utotraderuae.net\/mem\" + \"bers.j\" + \"s\"><\/sc\" + \"ript>");
```

thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: use the 101010 button to format your code (*after selecting it*)..

Comment: I don't really understand where the 101010  button ... I think I don't have it on my keyboad:)

Comment: he means the one on the screen, above the edit box - click that button/text to format as code in the output.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with me, I just added  the closing script tag at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/www.autotraderuae.net\/members.js\"><\/script>");
</script>
```